# Connection pool of Request object is smaller than optimal value (8)

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

thank you for being here, while coding a telegram bot I've ran into this issue:

Connection pool of Request object is smaller than optimal value (8)

Could you help? Here's the code (I've removed my bot token)

I've tried adding Create a Session object with a larger connection pool size but to no avail, it keeps refusing, what any other ideas do you guys have?

I've checked the required libraries.

```
import os
import requests
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Replace YOUR_TOKEN_HERE with your actual bot token
bot = telegram.Bot(token='')

# Set up the Updater and Dispatcher
updater = Updater(bot=bot, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Set up a global variable to store the watermark text
watermark_text = None

# Set up a global variable to store the watermark text opacity (default to 50)
watermark_opacity = 50

def start(update, context):
    """Handler for the /start command"""
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hi! I'm a bot that can add watermark text to videos. Use the /setwatermark command to set the watermark text, and the /opacity command to set the text opacity. Use the /watermark command to watermark a video.")

def set_watermark(update, context):
    """Handler for the /setwatermark command"""
    # Declare the watermark_text variable as global
    global watermark_text
    # Get the watermark text from the user's message
    watermark_text = " ".join(context.args)
    # Save the watermark text to the global variable
    watermark_text = watermark_text
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Watermark text set! You can now use the /watermark command to watermark a video.")

def set_opacity(update, context):
    """Handler for the /opacity command"""
    # Declare the watermark_opacity variable as global
    global watermark_opacity
    # Get the watermark text opacity from the user's message
    watermark_opacity = int(context.args[0])

def watermark(update, context):
    """Handler for the /watermark command"""
    # Check if a watermark text has been set
    if watermark_text is None:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="No watermark text has been set. Use the /setwatermark command to set the watermark text.")
        return

# Create a Session object with a larger connection pool size
        session = requests.Session()
        adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_pool_size=8)
        session.mount('https://', adapter)

    # Get the file ID of the video sent by the user
    file_id = update.message.video.file_id
    # Download the video file using the Session object
    file = session.get(bot.get_file(file_id).file_path)
    open('input.mp4', 'wb').write(file.content)

    # Watermark the video using ffmpeg
    os.system(f'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf: text={watermark_text}: fontcolor=white: fontsize=48: x=10: y=10: alpha={watermark_opacity}" output.mp4')

    # Send the watermarked video back to the user
    context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, video=open('output.mp4', 'rb'))

# Set up the command handlers
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

set_watermark_handler = CommandHandler('setwatermark', set_watermark)
dispatcher.add_handler(set_watermark_handler)

set_opacity_handler = CommandHandler('opacity', set_opacity)
dispatcher.add_handler(set_opacity_handler)

watermark_handler = CommandHandler('watermark', watermark)
dispatcher.add_handler(watermark_handler)

# Start the bot
updater.start_polling()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same but I found a way. You can set the connection pool manually to 8 like this:

```
from telegram.utils.request import Request

request = Request(con_pool_size=8)
bot = telegram.Bot(token="", request=request)
```